# Trying to store a dictionary within a dictionary overwrites existing values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary which calls the name of a restaurant, and the type of cuisine it is known for.

I wanted to create a dictionary so I could call each restaurant type up later. The problem is every method I've tried so far overwrites my value pairs which pertain to each key.

I understand that I somehow need to alter each key so as not to overwrite my values, but so far every attempt I've tried has not been successful. To circumvent that, I tried to place a dictionary within a dictionary. The  input/output of the code is also seen below.

Some of the things I attempted are below:

```
restaurant_dict[restaurant] = value
```

main:

```
from nine_two import Restaurant

def increment(min_num, max_num, name_of_variable):
    #enter the name of the variable and how many times to increment it
    list_1 = []
    for x in range(min_num,max_num):
        list_1.append(f"{name_of_variable}_{x}")
    
    for variable in list_1:
        #return a list of the incremented variables
        return list_1
    
#Created dictionaries & variables
restaurant_dict = {} 
restaurant_dict_2 = {}
list_1 = increment(1,4,"Restaurant")


for variable in list_1:
    print(f"\n{variable}:")
    user_restaurant = input("Enter name of restaurant: ")
    user_cuisine = input("Enter cuisine of restaurant: ")

    #FIXME attempt to store variables in a callable dictionary
    restaurant_dict_2[variable] = restaurant_dict
    restaurant_dict["Restaurant"] = user_restaurant
    restaurant_dict["Cuisine type"] = user_cuisine
    print(restaurant_dict_2)
    
    #ignore this
    variable = Restaurant(user_restaurant,user_cuisine)
    variable.describe_restaurant()
    variable.open_restaurant()
```

Imported code is:

```
class Restaurant:
    """Creates a restaurant"""
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        """Intialize name and cuisine attributes."""
        self.name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine = cuisine_type
        
    def describe_restaurant(self):
        """describes the restaurant"""
        print(f"The {self.name} is a restaurant that specializes in {self.cuisine}.")
        
    def open_restaurant(self):
        """Opens the restaurant"""
        print(f"The {self.name} is now open!")
```

[Output of code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejKBJ.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of text when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes in two parts:

1. How to fix your dictionary problem.
2. You don't need to use a dictionary at all.

---

**Part 1: How to fix the problem with your dictionaries:**

Your problem is that you assign the *same* `restaurant_dict` to multiple keys. When you do `dict2['key1'] = dict1`, you didn't create a copy of `dict1` to assign to `dict2['key1']`. So when later you do `dict2['key2'] = dict1`, the same dict gets assigned to both `key1` and `key2`. Then, when you change `dict1['name']`, since the same `dict1` is referenced by both `key1` and `key2`, it changes the value in both places.

To fix this, move the line `restaurant_dict = {}` *inside* your `for variable in list_1:` loop, so that you create a new dictionary for each restaurant.

```
    #FIXME attempt to store variables in a callable dictionary
    restaurant_dict = {}
    restaurant_dict_2[variable] = restaurant_dict
    restaurant_dict["Restaurant"] = user_restaurant
    restaurant_dict["Cuisine type"] = user_cuisine
```

Or, better yet, you can simply assign the `Restaurant` and `Cuisine type` keys while you're creating the dict

```
    #FIXME attempt to store variables in a callable dictionary
    restaurant_dict = {"Restaurant": user_restaurant, "Cuisine type": user_cuisine}
    restaurant_dict_2[variable] = restaurant_dict
```

---

**Part 2: You don't need to use a dictionary at all**

Usually when you use a dictionary, you want to *map* a key to a value. For example, if you were creating a directory of restaurants for every cuisine, you could have a dictionary where the keys were the cuisine type, and the values were a list of restaurants serving that cuisine.

However, in this case, it seems like you are simply making a *list* of restaurants (because your keys are sequential), so a simple list would suffice. Also, since you have a class to represent a restaurant, you just need to create an object of this class and append it to your list. No need to create dictionaries and `Restaurant` objects.

```
restaurants = []
for _ in range(num_restaurants):
    user_restaurant = input("Enter name of restaurant: ")
    user_cuisine = input("Enter cuisine of restaurant: ")
    
    restaurant = Restaurant(user_restaurant, user_cuisine)
    restaurants.append(restaurant)

    restaurant.describe_restaurant()
    restaurant.open_restaurant()
```

If you wanted to do the thing I mentioned in the previous paragraph and create a map of cuisines with restaurants, you could then process this list into a dict:

```
cuisine_restaurants = {}
for rest in restaurants:
    cuisine = rest.cuisine
    if cuisine not in cuisine_restaurants:
        cuisine_restaurants[cuisine] = []

    cuisine_restaurants[cuisine].append(rest)
```

Then, you could ask the user for a cuisine, and show all restaurants that serve that cuisine without having to re-iterate over the entire `restaurants` list:

```
c = input("What would you like to eat today?")
suggested_rest = cuisine_restaurants.get(c, []) # .get() returns the second argument if the key given by c doesn't exist

print("You could eat at: ")
for r in suggested_rest:
    r.describe_restaurant()
```

Comment: Unrelated nitpick: What you get in a restaurant is _cuisine_, but that is totally irrelevant to the programming problem